# Search objects by comparing the objects in the object, which is in the list

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

There's a possibility to find a objects using similar expression as below?

```
List<Object> findPracticesByHeadquartersCityRegionOrInstitutionsCityRegion(List<Region> regions)
```

The object looks like this:

```
public class Practice{
  private Headquarters headquarters;
  private List<Institution> institutions;
}
```

The Headquarters and an Institution have the variable City.
City have the variable of Region.

Problem is a List. Is possible to did something similar to loop inside query to check every object inside this list?

***I use mongodb.***

Regards,
Thank you in advance